# Haskell - Values do not save after a ForM loop

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to be able to create a program in haskell that can an find an increasing subsequence from a list of numbers (not yet completed, this part is to compute for each sublist what the longest increasing subsequence is within that sublist). This program essentially take take from an input such as

```
1
5
1 2 9 6 8
```

where the first line is the number of test cases and the second line being the number of numbers in the specific test case, and the third line being the test case itself. It is looking for the multiple increasing sequences within the test case. Here is what I have so far:

```
main = do   
    inputCases <- getLine
    let cases = (read inputCases :: Int)
    forM [1..cases] $ \num -> do
        inputNumbers <- getLine
        let numbers = (read inputNumbers :: Int)  
        something <- getLine
        let singlewords = words something
            list = f singlewords
        let hello = grid numbers numbers 0
        let second  = hello
        print list
        forM [0..numbers] $ \check -> do
            forM [check..numbers] $ \check2 -> do
                let val = 1
                let keeper = val
                forM [check..check2] $ \check3 -> do
                    let val = getVal hello list keeper check check2 check3
                    let keeper = val
                    return()
                print check
                print check2
                print val
                let hello = updateMatrix second val (check, check2)
                let second = hello


f :: [String] -> [Int]
f = map read

grid :: Int -> Int -> a -> [[a]]
grid x y = replicate y . replicate x

getVal :: [[Int]] -> [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
getVal m b second x y z = 
    if b!!z < b!!y && 1+m!!x!!z > second then 1+m!!x!!z
    else second

updateMatrix :: [[a]] -> a -> (Int, Int) -> [[a]]
updateMatrix m x (r,c) =
  take r m ++
  [take c (m !! r) ++ [x] ++ drop (c + 1) (m !! r)] ++
  drop (r + 1) m
```

However, my problem is that once the program exits the ForM loop, it does not save the variable "hello" or anything that was declared in the for loop. Is there a better way of doing this? Would recursion work in this case? I am not quite sure how that would be implemented
lis[i][j] will hold the length of the longest increasing subsequence in {a[i], ..., a[j]}

here is the python code that I am trying to translate. Given this code, is there a better way of doing this besides the way I am currently trying to do it?

```
T = int(input())
for t in range(0, T):

    n = int(input())
    a = list(map(int, input().split()))

    lis = [[0 for j in range(0, n)] for i in range(0, n)]

    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            val = 1
            for k in range(i, j):
                if(a[k] < a[j] and 1 + lis[i][k] > val):
                    val = 1 + lis[i][k]
            lis[i][j] = val
```

Comment: `let` is not assignment. You are trying to program imperatively using a purely functional programming language. I'd recommend you start from a Haskell tutorial. Do not attempt to translate from another language, especially from a non functional one. (This goes both ways: do not attempt to translate Haskell into imperative programming languages)

Answer (score 2):

In my other answer, I discussed the answer to the question you asked about how to store information for retrieval later when in a `forM` loop. In this answer, I will discuss the idiomatic translation of `for` loops from other languages; generally this is *not* to produce a `forM` loop in Haskell.

Because this is an excellent programming exercise, I don't want to give away the answer -- there's a lot of joy and learning to be had from solving the problem yourself. But I do want to illustrate an alternative approach. To keep all the interesting bits of the translation I cooked up of your Python code, I will solve a slightly easier problem in a slightly stylized way: instead of `lis[i][j]` giving the length of the longest increasing subsequence between indices `i` and `j` in the original list, we will have `lis[i][j]` give the largest value between indices `i` and `j` in the original list.

The idea will go like this: instead of iterating over indices `i` and `j`, we'll iterate over suffixes starting at `i`, then over prefixes of suffixes starting at `i` and ending at `j`. To begin with, we'll do the naive thing of just calling `maximum` on each infix expression. So:

```
import Data.List

maxes0 a =
    [ [ maximum inf
      | inf <- tail (inits suff)
      ]
    | suff <- init (tails a)
    ]
```

For example, we can try it on your example list in ghci:

```
> maxes0 [1,2,9,6,8]
[[1,2,9,9,9],[2,9,9,9],[9,9,9],[6,8],[8]]
```

Note right away that there's a difference in shape here: where in Python we produced a square result, here we produce a triangular one, omitting the useless entries that do not correspond to actual infix chunks of the original list. (It's easy to reintroduce dummy values if you actually need a square result for some reason.)

This is already pretty good, and quite idiomatic; however, there is one part of the Python code that it does not capture well yet: the Python code reuses previously computed values to do some dynamic programming. This can be done to the above code, as well, though it does require a bit of mental gymnastics the first few times you see it. We will use laziness and recursion to make available earlier results when computing later ones.

The idea here will be to keep a rolling max as we traverse the suffix, merging as we go the list of maximums of infixes with the new values we see in the suffix. So:

```
maxes1 a =
    [ let row = head suff : zipWith max row (tail suff)
      in row
    | suff <- init (tails a)
    ]
```

We can see in ghci that this works just the same:

```
> maxes1 [1,2,9,6,8]
[[1,2,9,9,9],[2,9,9,9],[9,9,9],[6,8],[8]]
```

You can combine these two ideas (making the already-computed bits available via laziness+recursion, and making the infix list available by nested list comprehensions) to produce an idiomatic translation of the Python code which is completely pure, does not mention list indices anywhere, and does not use `forM`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I think I was quite unclear with the exercise, and instead of only finding the longest increasing subsequence, Instead of finding one increasing subsequence, we will find multiple increasing subsequences with the following two constraints:
- The length of each subsequence should be at least of a given size k.
- If a subsequence starts at index i and ends at index j, no other subsequence can start or end in the range i to j (inclusive), i.e., no other subsequence can have any elements in
between index i and j (inclusive), i.e., the subsequences cannot overlap

Answer (score 1):

`forM` returns a list of values, one each per input element in the list it's handed, with whatever you compute in the body of the function you give to `forM`. So you can extract information from the loop body with the usual `do`-notation binding syntax. Here's a simple example that asks the user whether to double each number in a list:

```
import Control.Monad
vals = [1..5]
main = do
    vals' <- forM vals $ \val -> do
        v <- getLine
        return (if v == "yes" then val*2 else val)
    print vals'
```

An example of running it:

```
> main
yes
yes
no
no
yes
[2,4,3,4,10]
```

Though this example returned numbers for simplicity, you may return arbitrary information of interest from each loop iteration in this way.